# Isomorphic react apps + ajax

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic

I have the following scenario which I assume is quite typical yet I can't finding any boilerplate / library for the job.

1. we have an react component meant for isomorphic usage
2. on client side, it would fetch additional data via ajax upon navigation
3. on server side, the very same data is available from a certain js function, ajax call should be avoided

I try not to use redux.
[react-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async) seems close enough but its last commit was 2 years old and doesn't run with latest version of react.

Edit:  Perhaps its clearer with an example?

Let's say we are coding a blog site, there is an isomorphic react component that renders the title of a blog.

- On client side, the component would fetch the blog title via ajax
- On server side, the component should fetch the title from DB, not ajax

How do I structure my react component to achieve the two requirements above?

Comment: im not sure i understood. You want to fetch some data from a server when the component is rendered? if so you can use Axios to fetch data when executing ComponentWillMount()

Comment: Use meteor : https://www.meteor.com/

Comment: @Vandervidi you described the client side right.  my question is how do I code the react component so that on server side the data for the component will come from DB, not ajax

Comment: @Garfield The proper way to get some data from a DB to a client is to send a HTTP request to a server. The server connects to your DB, gets some data, and at the end the server returns the DB data to your client with a HTTP response.

Comment: @Vandervidi are we talking about **isomorphic** react apps here?

Comment: @Garfield i was not talking about isomorphic app